# Oracle to_date within SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python, sql, oracle, sqlalchemy

Using plain **Oracle SQL**, I would use:

```
select *
from mytable
where 
to_date(date_d, 'dd-mon-yyyy') == to_date('01-Jan-2013', 'dd-mon-yyyy')
```

Now using SQLAlchemy, I'm at a loss.

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = myTable.c.date_d == datetime(2013, 1, 1)
q = session.query(myTable).filter(dt)
q.first()
```

Will give me incorrect results, because date_d is **varchar**, so it won't translate to **date** unless I run an Oracle function to convert the datatype within the query. How can I do that?

Comment: Step 1 - stop storing dates as text.

Comment: @DanBracuk, consider this an intellectual exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I didn't need to convert the datatype. SQLAlchemy seems to do that transparently. However, If I feel like doing it explicitly:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

dt = func.to_date(myTable.c.date_d, 'dd-mon-yyyy') == datetime(2013, 1, 1)
q = session.query(dt)
q.first()
```

My incorrect results were due to an unrelated mistake.